# how to populate a numpy 2D array with function returning a numpy 1D array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have function predicton like

```
def predictions(degree):
  some magic,
  return an np.ndarray([0..100])
```

I want to call this function for a few values of degree and use it to populate a larger np.ndarray (n=2), filling each row with the outcome of the function `predictions`. It seems like a simple task but somehow I cant get it working. I tried with

```
for deg in [1,2,4,8,10]:
   np.append(result, predictions(deg),axis=1)
```

with result being an `np.empty(100)`. But that failed with `Singleton array array(1) cannot be considered a valid collection.`

I could not get `fromfunction` it only works on a coordinate tuple, and the irregular list of degrees is not covered in the docs.

Comment: The singleton array(1) error message was originating from function predictions.` result = np.array([predictions(1), predictions(2), predictions(4),predictions(8)])` is working but not very nice..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use `np.ndarray` until you are older and wiser!  I couldn't even use it without rereading the docs.

```
arr1d = np.array([1,2,3,4,5])
```

is the correct way to construct a 1d array from a list of numbers.

Also don't use `np.append`.  I won't even add the 'older and wiser' qualification.  It doesn't work in-place; and is slow when used in a loop.

A good way of building a 2 array from 1d arrays is:

```
alist = []
for i in ....:
    alist.append(<alist or 1d array>)
arr = np.array(alist)
```

provided all the sublists have the same size, arr should be a 2d array.

This is equivalent to building a 2d array from

```
np.array([[1,2,3], [4,5,6]])
```

that is a list of lists.

Or a list comprehension:

```
np.array([predictions(i) for i in range(10)])
```

Again, `predictions` must all return the same length arrays or lists.

Comment: I'm too old to get any wiser :-) but your answer has helped me. ndarray was not a free choice but a mandatory excercise outcome.

Comment: I (aesthetically) like the list comprehension, but not sure how expensive it is? (Performance is not my my top priority though).

Comment: List comprehension is generally a bit faster than the equivalent loop with append.  The interpreter constructs a tighter set of bytecodes.

Answer (score 2):

`append` is in the boring section of numpy. here you know the shape in advance

```
len_predictions = 100

def predictions(degree):
    return np.ones((len_predictions,))

degrees = [1,2,4,8,10]
result = np.empty((len(degrees), len_predictions))
for i, deg in enumerate(degrees):
    result[i] = predictions(deg)
```

if you want to store the degree somehow, you can use custom dtypes

Comment: This is the way +1. `append` is expensive (with anything), avoid where possible.